# Emacs HTML Export Options (Post- and Preamble)

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is there a way I can declare some HTML pre- and post-amble content **in a buffer** (and only applying to that buffer) itself without needing to create a new `org-publish-project-alist` project or customizing the default `org-html-preamble` and `org-html-postamble`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `org-html-preamble` and `org-html-postamble` (and `org-html-postamble-format`) are available to allow you to modify these components. This is explained in the org mode manual node [(org) HTML preamble and postamble](https://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-preamble-and-postamble.html)

If you set these variables as 'local variables', the changes will only apply to the current buffer. i.e., append the following to your .org file:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-html-preamble: "MY PREAMBLE \
#  which can span multiple lines, if we escape the newlines!\
#  literal newlines need to be inserted like this:\n Next line."
# End:
```

You will need to reload the file, or call `M-x normal-mode`, for this to take effect.