# Emacs HTML Preamble in setup file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I have a project with a few org files that are exported as HTML to create a website. All org files that correspond to web pages have `#+SETUPFILE: my-setup.org` declared in it. And the `my-setup.org` file have all the common settings like the following.

```
#+language: en
#+html_doctype: html5
#+html_head: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
......
```

Is there a way I can declare an HTML preamble content in the `my-setup.org`, so that it is applied to all the exported webpages.

I have already tried using the following solution from [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41108/36549), and **it doesn't work** when added to `my-setup.org`.

```
# Local Variables:
# org-html-preamble: "My custom preamble!"
# End:
```

I don't want to add this preamble to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file where I have the `org-publish-project-alist` configured, as this preamble should be part of the project repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a file `.dir-locals.el` in the top-level directory of your project hierarchy and adding this content to it:

```el
((org-mode . ((org-html-preamble . "My custom preamble!"))))
```

See [Per-Directory Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) in the Emacs manual.