# How do I get org-mode to add yaml frontmatter to the top of the exported .html output?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I use org-mode to generate webpages for github pages, but now I want org-mode to add the following text (yaml frontmatter) to the top of every .html file that it creates when exporting to HTML:

```
---
permalink: name-of-permalink
---
```

I can get org-mode to export that text to the .html files using the following lines:

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
---
permalink: name-of-permalink
---
#+END_EXPORT
```

But unfortunately, the org-mode exporter places the YMF *after* the table of contents, <head>, and all the other HTML code that appears at the top of .html exports.

Is there a way to override the default settings, so that the Yaml Frontmatter is always placed at the very beginning of the file *before* all of that code?

Comment: You might find this helpful [Emacs HTML Export Options (Post- and Preamble)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41108/28451).

Comment: Okay, I read that answer, and the page from the org-mode manual that it linked.
When I set "org-html-preamble" to an example preamble, it doesn't work...

If I'm understanding this correctly, this what I need to do:
1. Define a function that returns a string of the permalink-text that you want to use.
2. The function will retrieve this string from the org file's filename.
3. Define org-html-preamble as that function.
4. Do something else to make it work...
And hopefully the correct preamble text will be added to each org file's HTML exported output.

Comment: In which HTML section should this go? It looks like CSS to me, but it's not clear from the question. Depending on *where* exactly it is to go in the HTML output, different methods might be needed.

Comment: This doesn't involve any CSS at all. I want the permalink text to appear at the very top of the HTML file. If it appears anywhere else but the very beginning of the file, then Github Pages will fail to detect and create the permalink variable correctly. Unfortunately, I don't think toggling the org-html-preamble variable will be enough to resolve this, and I don't know how to write the function that I was thinking of either.

Comment: OK - what is `name-of-permalink`? Is that a fixed string that Github Pages fills in or is that something that *you* have to provide to the export process? IOW, what exactly is going to be added to the top of each HTML file: the literal string you show above or some variation of it where `name-of-permalink` is a placeholder for the actual value? Note that I know nothing about Github Pages.

Comment: `name-of-permalink` is a variable that Github Pages stores in order to enable people to structure the directories of their source code different from the directories of their (running) website. It can be a path that uses other variables for structuring the URL differently, but in my case, I just want `name-of-permalink` to be the name of the webpage's HTML file, as it will be the name displayed in the webpage's URL. Now that I thought of it, it might be easier to permalink entire directories, instead of embedding the permalinks into the HTML webpages, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: I don't understand the workflow. Can you provide a link to the Github documentation that describes this workflow?

Comment: This is the documentation, but I don't understand the syntax: https://ashmaroli.github.io/jekyll/docs/permalinks/

Comment: I'm now thinking that there might be a way to accomplish this by editing the variable `org-html-xml-declaration`, since it controls the text that gets placed at the top of every HTML file. Perhaps, I could prepend the string "---\\permalink: :basename\\---\\" to the variable, but I would have to figure out how to only prepend that yaml frontmatter to only my github pages, and not other .html pages.